# STM32F401RE Nucleo board, cannot toggle user LED

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, stm32f4, nucleo

I am trying to figure out how to toggle an LED on the Nucleo board and I just don't see the User LED toggle.  Looking online it seems this is all you have to do.  Has anyone else encountered this issue?

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"

int main(void)
{
    int counter = 0;
    SystemInit();

    GPIO_InitTypeDef temp;
    temp.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    temp.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;    // Push Pull
    temp.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5;
    temp.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Low_Speed;
    temp.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

    GPIO_Init( GPIOA, &temp );

    while( 1 )
    {
        if ( counter++ > 10000 )
        {
            GPIO_ToggleBits( GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_5 );
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to write

```
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
```

in order to enable GPIOA.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot enable an AHB1 peripheral clock using the AHB2 clock control.

```
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    ^^^^                   ^^^
```

> *"I just don't see the User LED toggle."*

Even when you correctly enable the GPIO clock, you are toggling the output very fast (MHz order) and `counter` serves no obvious purpose.  If a flashing LED was your aim, that will not do it; you'll just see an LED at somewhat less than full brightness - you need a delay between each toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Clifford is absolutely right, the LED is "toggling" way to fast. The STM32F401RE supposedly is running at 168Mhz. Change your counter value from 10.000 to e.g. 50.000.000 to see the LED toggling at an appropriate rate.

Comment: I am right, but changing the counter value will not solve the problem - not in that code.  Moreover it would need also to be volatile, and using a software counter for timing delay is a bad idea in any case.  Cortex-M has a SYSTICK timer for this.        I deliberately chose not to offer a fix as solutions and better methods are legion.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, but the counter does not have to be volatile. Holding the counter in a register and incrementing the value in there is fair enough. Of course this is not a good solution, but it will have a visible result for Godspped and he can continue his work. I choose not to offer complicated solutions, like using the SYSTICK timer, when the user is already struggling to get a GPIO port toggling. Obviously the user would be overburdened with it at this point. Don't be so harsh.

Comment: Any decent optimizing compiler will remove an empty loop, where the control variables is not used; unless it is declared volatile.

Comment: You have in fact offered no solution because as it is, the counter is not in a delay loop, it simply counts toggle events uslessly.  You need an answer that stands alone rather than referring to other answers - even if you are partially duplicating other answers as I have.  Your answer adds a new and valid point, but should be complete in itself. Referencing my answer will be meaningless if I were to delete it.  SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Note also that while the F401 _can_ run at 168MHz, it need not, and unless the PLL and HS clock have been configured in the startup before main, it will be running the internal oscillator at 16MHz.